# Avoiding re-render unchanged items

Tags: reactjs, performance, react-memo

I'm trying to improve the performance of a long list with changeable items using `React.memo`, but I'm getting strange behavior.

**Steps to reproduce:**

1 - Go to the sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/great-payne-4qudz?file=/src/App.js)

2 - Press add on the first item

3 - Press add on the second item

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [list, setList] = useState([
    { id: 1, qtd: 0 },
    { id: 2, qtd: 0 },
    { id: 3, qtd: 0 },
    { id: 4, qtd: 0 }
  ]);

  const onAdd = (id, qtd) => {
    setList(
      list.map((item) => {
        if (item.id === id) {
          return { ...item, qtd };
        } else {
          return item;
        }
      })
    );
  };

  return (
    <ul>
      {list.map((item) => (
        <Item {...item} onChange={onAdd} />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

const Item = React.memo(({ id, qtd, onChange }) => {
  console.log("Rendering -> " + id);

  return (
    <li>
      <span>{qtd}</span>
      <button onClick={() => onChange(id, qtd + 1)}>Add</button>
    </li>
  );
}, areEqual);

function areEqual(prev, next) {
  return prev.qtd === next.qtd;
}

export default App;
```

Comment: What is your issue?

Comment: Have you tried adding the `key` property to the items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by using the latest state of list

```
const App = () => {
  const [list, setList] = useState([
    { id: 1, qtd: 0 },
    { id: 2, qtd: 0 },
    { id: 3, qtd: 0 },
    { id: 4, qtd: 0 }
  ]);

  const onAdd = (id, qtd) => {
    setList((l) =>
      l.map((item) => {
        if (item.id === id) {
          return { ...item, qtd };
        } else {
          return item;
        }
      })
    );
  };

  return (
    <ul>
      {list.map((item) => (
        <Item key={item.id} {...item} onChange={onAdd} />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};
```

Also added key as stated by Ngọc Hy

https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-grothendieck-z8uxf?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1):

I have modified your add function. And have added the key attribute to the item or the li element as that helps react determine which element has changed in the DOM.

```
const onAdd = (id, qtd) => {
    const oldList = [...list];
    oldList.forEach((element) => {
      if (element.id === id) {
        element.qtd=qtd;
      }
    });
    setList(oldList);
  };

    <ul>
      {list.map((item) => (
        <Item key={item.id} {...item} onChange={onAdd} />
      ))}
    </ul>
```